# Converting class properties in to an array of [JsonPropertyName, Value]

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Is there anyway to take some C# class and convert each property into a string array of [JsonPropertyName, value] without creating JSON via strings. I have been trying to serialize the object to JSON using newtonsoft.Json but I can't get the properties to appear in the same way as the desired output.

```
public class UserCredentials
{
    [JsonProperty("InternetGatewayDevice.WANDevice.1.WANConnectionDevice.1.WANPPPConnection.1.Username")]
    public string Username;

    [JsonProperty("InternetGatewayDevice.WANDevice.1.WANConnectionDevice.1.WANPPPConnection.1.Password")]
    public string Password;
}
```

Desired JSON output:

```
{"name":"setParameterValues", 
    "parameterValues": [
        ["InternetGatewayDevice.WANDevice.1.WANConnectionDevice.1.WANPPPConnection.1.Username", "tester@test.net"],
        ["InternetGatewayDevice.WANDevice.1.WANConnectionDevice.1.WANPPPConnection.1.Password", "hello"]
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the object to the array of properties and then serialize it.
Something like this:

```
public class Test
{
    [JsonProperty("TestJsonString")]
    public string TestFieldString { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("TestJsonInt")]
    public int TestFieldInt { get; set; }

    public int TestFieldInt2 { get; set; }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var data = new Test() {TestFieldInt = 1, TestFieldString = "11"};
        var testArray = data.GetType().GetProperties()
            .Where(x => x.GetCustomAttributes(true).Any(attr => attr is JsonPropertyAttribute))
            .Select(x => new []
            {
                (x.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(JsonPropertyAttribute), true).Single() as JsonPropertyAttribute).PropertyName,
                x.GetGetMethod().Invoke(data, null) == null ? "" : x.GetGetMethod().Invoke(data, null).ToString()
            });
        var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(testArray);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have `JSON` property and the value as you asked in the question, and according to my understanding, with the use of `Newtonsoft.Json` like below,

```
string x = JsonConvert.SerializeObject([YourObject],Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None, new JsonSerializerSettings { MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.ReadAhead} );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom JSON serializer. For some examples, check these links ([link1](http://blog.maskalik.com/asp-net/json-net-implement-custom-serialization/), [link2](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/09/30/custom-serialization-with-json-net-webapi-and-bsondocument.aspx)).

Here is how your code may look like (it's only draft, you have to use reflection properly):

```
    private class PropertyNamesSerializer : JsonConverter
    {
        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            writer.WriteStartObject();
            writer.WritePropertyName("name");
            writer.WriteValue("setParameterValues");
            writer.WritePropertyName("parameterValues");
            writer.WriteStartArray();
            writer.WriteStartObject();
            foreach (var property in value.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                var attribute = property.GetCustomAttribute<JsonPropertyAttribute>();
                writer.WritePropertyName(attribute.PropertyName);
                writer.WriteValue(property.GetValue(value));
            }
            writer.WriteEndObject();
            writer.WriteEndArray();
            writer.WriteEndObject();
        }
    // other methods
```

Usage:

```
    [JsonConverter(typeof(PropertyNamesSerializer))]
    public class UserCredentials
    {
        [JsonProperty("InternetGatewayDevice.WANDevice.1.WANConnectionDevice.1.WANPPPConnection.1.Username")]
        public string Username { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("InternetGatewayDevice.WANDevice.1.WANConnectionDevice.1.WANPPPConnection.1.Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new UserCredentials() {Username = "test", Password = "something"}));
    }
```